# Hi, I can't to insert a data using hibernate with spring framework in heroku

Tags: spring, hibernate, heroku

I'm new using the framework I created a database manually in the postgreSQL dababase at Heroku and y created the models tagged with anotations and I created a hibernate.cfg.xml file with the connection details, I created a route to insert some data but it's not inserting nothing.

Thanks by your help.

```
    @RequestMapping("/success")
    String success() {
      SessionFactory sf = new Configuration()
              .configure("hibernate.cfg.xml")
              .addAnnotatedClass(Technologies.class)
              .buildSessionFactory();
      Session s = sf.openSession();
      
      try {
            Technologies t1 = new Technologies("Java");
            Technologies t2 = new Technologies("Python");
            Technologies t3 = new Technologies("PHP");
            Technologies t4 = new Technologies("Bash");
            Technologies t5 = new Technologies("HTML");
            Technologies t6 = new Technologies("CSS");
            Technologies t7 = new Technologies("JavaScript");             
            /*
            SocialNetworks sn1 = new SocialNetworks("Facebook", "https://www.facebook.com/...");
            SocialNetworks sn2 = new SocialNetworks("GitHub", "https://github.com/...");
            SocialNetworks sn3 = new SocialNetworks("FCC", "https://www.freecodecamp.org/...");
            SocialNetworks sn4 = new SocialNetworks("Twitter", "https://twitter.com/...");
            SocialNetworks sn5 = new SocialNetworks("Email", "mailto:...");
            
            Comunities c1 = new Comunities("images/artlike.png", "Artonline", "...");
            Comunities c2 = new Comunities("images/fcc.png", "FCC Study Group", "https://github.com/...");
            Comunities c3 = new Comunities("images/dragonjar.png", "DragonJar Comunity", "http://comunidad.dragonjar.info/");
            */
            
            s.beginTransaction();
            s.save(t1);
            s.save(t2);
            s.save(t3);
            s.save(t4);
            s.save(t5);
            s.save(t6);
            s.save(t7);             
            s.getTransaction().commit();
            s.close();
      } catch (Exception e) {
          e.getStackTrace();
          s.getTransaction().rollback();
      } finally {
          sf.close();
      }
      return "success";
  }
```

The errors in the heroku logs are:

```
2020-11-15T15:50:21.431596+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/success" host=test.herokuapp.com request_id=dfc56fa6-2c5b-4736-b31b-212e7eee8a94 fwd="190.84.149.124" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=1760ms status=404 bytes=263 protocol=https
```

[image: Data in the PossgreSQL table]

Comment: Is it running locally and you can see the records at your local Postgres?

Comment: Not, I'm locally but it's configured to the Heroku remote database.

Comment: Then what are your local logs? Heroku logs are not relevant in this case.